# How to make a list that can show the changeable content

Tags: android

I have build an application in android. This app needs to display a list of text, but the list of text increase continuously. It means user can see increased list of text. Each text is separated by a horizontal row. It looks like google market when market try to show list of applications. How can i do in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention where the data came from but let's suppose that you have an `ArrayList` of your model `Text`.

Steps:

- Add a `ListView` to your layout
- Extend `ArrayAdapter`
- Set this new adapter to your `ListView`
- Modify the array adding/removing new stuff
- Notify the `ListView` that the data has changed using the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Comment: hi Macarse! Thanks for your answer! I mean my list can change continuously but users don't have to wait. It looks like google market when market try to show applications on a category! Thanks.

Comment: @Nguyên Thành: If you are willing to do something like that I would recommend you search for `Endless Adapter`. It's a piece of code done by Mark Murphy which does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks! I think i have what i need. Thanks Macarse!